# How to getting into the "All Photos" Albums directly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

My code is like this:

```
oldPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
   oldPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   oldPicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:oldPicker.sourceType];
}
oldPicker.delegate = self;
oldPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self presentViewController:oldPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The effects is when I click the button,it shows me the albums choosing view,but I just want to skipping the albums choosing view and directly show the "All Photos" albums.

I have tried to setting the `sourceType` to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`, but it shows me the "Moments" albums but not the "All Photos" albums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that using `UIImagePickerController`.

There are only 3 values available for `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType`.

> ```
> enum
> {
>   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary,
>   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
>   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
> };
> typedef NSUInteger UIImagePickerControllerSourceType;
> ```
>
> **Constants**
>
> ```
> UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary
> ```
>
> Specifies the device’s photo library as the source for the image picker controller.
>
> ```
> UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
> ```
>
> Specifies the device’s built-in camera as the source for the image picker controller. Indicate the specific camera you want (front or
>   rear, as available) by using the cameraDevice property.
>
> ```
> UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
> ```
>
> Specifies the device’s Camera Roll album as the source for the image picker controller. If the device does not have a camera,
>   specifies the Saved Photos album as the source.

So for achieving the scenario you mentioned you need to write your own image picker. There is a custom control available, you can check that also [**CTAssetsPickerController**](https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController)